# How to avoid re-rendering with new SAP UI5 control?

Tags: sapui5

I have already created a new SAP UI5 control to render a chart. The chart will be drawn by **D3js**. That control is named **MyControl1**.

I added the **MyControl1** into an **IconTabFilter** of **IconTabBar** control. My issue is when I switch to another tab then back to **MyControl1** tab, the render function in **MyControl1** will be triggered again but I don't expect that action. so I need your help **how can I avoid re-rendering?**

Thanks

Comment: i think you are calling you function from onBeforeRendering,onAfterRendering or RouteMatch. To avoid this simply  create one global Boolean variable in onInit function and use as if condition once your code is executed at the bottom of your function code make global Boolean variable false. this will make sure your code is executed once only.